# Session condition in button

Tags: php, html, session

I already done create my website, now I want 1 of my button, 
can only run if you have logged in, check the session and do the search function, but if not then the modal with login form will pop up to ask for login information.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-8">
   <button type="button" name="search" id="search" class="btn btn-info btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip modal" data-target="#modal-form" data-placement="top" data-html="true">Search</button>
</div>
```

Here is on my php

```
if (isset($_POST["nikName"]) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE MATCH (NIK, name) AGAINST (:nikName IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bindValue(":nikName", "\"".$_POST["nikName"]."\"");
} else if (isset($_POST["nik"]) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE NIK = :nik";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bindValue(":nik", $_POST["nik"]);    
} else {
   // Redirect to login page.
   header('#modal-form');
}
```

And cause I want the session only work on 1 html page, I only need to write `session_start();` in that 1 php file too right? 
Thank You.

Comment: While creating the session store it like $_SESSION['key'] = 'somevalue';
Before calling the search code, just check the session exists for the given key or not. If session exists go ahead, else redirect to login page.

Comment: the login form is on the same page, but made on modal type

Answer (score 0):

Providing just HTML, is not really going to help to solve the problem. So I am going to make assumptions here.

Check if the user sessions and GET request have been made. If those two are valid, proceed by doing a search query. Or else, you can redirect them to login page.

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['search'] && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  // Do the search query
} else {
   // Redirect to login page.
   header('Location: ./login.php');
   exit();
}
```

Again. If you provide the PHP logic, on how you're doing it, we might be able to help you more relevantly.